# How to extract textures?

Tags: texture-baking

I'm working on a project in which I want to render the stream lines of a flow simulation in a system. I did the simulation and then I exported the stream lines in x3d format to blender from paraview since blender is capable to opening x3d files. Now I want to export the stream lines along with the texture but I'm unable to do so, I have never tried blender and I saw a lot of tutorial to export textures but nothing worked. Please help, I have attached the picture below. Is it possible to extract the texture from this model and save it as an image because x3d file does not come with any texture image.
[image]